# Replacing string values in a FeatureCollection with numbers in google earth engine

Tags: replace, shapes, feature-extraction, google-earth-engine

I have a `FeatureCollection` with a column named `Dominance` which has classified regions into stakeholder dominance. In this case, `Dominance` contains values as strings; specifically 'Small', 'Medium', 'Large' and 'Others'.
I want to replace these values/strings with 1,2,3 and 4. For that, I use the codes below:

```java
var Shape = ee.FeatureCollection('XYZ')
var Shape_custom = Shape.select(['Dominance'])

var conditional = function(feat) {
  return ee.Algorithms.If(feat.get('Dominance').eq('Small'),
  feat.set({class: 1}),
  feat)
}
var test = Shape_custom.map(conditional)
## This I plan to repeat for all classes
```

However, I am not able to change the values. The error I am getting is `feat.get(...).eq is not a function`.
What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to do this kind of mapping is using a dictionary. That way you do not need more code for each additional case.

```js
var mapping = ee.Dictionary({
  'Small': 1,
  'Medium': 2,
  'Large': 3,
  'Others': 4
});

var mapped = Shape
  .select(['Dominance'])
  .map(function (feature) {
    return feature.set('class', mapping.get(feature.get('Dominance')));
  });
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/8c58d9d24e6bfeca04e2a92b76d623a2